# tableView.reloadData() not calling heightForHeaderInSection?

Tags: swift, uitableview, height, xcode7, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a tableView with different heights for the header in the sections. When the orientation changes I want to update the height for the headers.

But I've noticed that calling `tableView.reloadData()` does not affect the method heightForHeaderInSection.

How can I change header height on orientation change?

P.S 
**delegate has been set.**

**heightForHeaderInSection:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if(section == 1) { return screenHeight - 300 }
    else { return 0 }

}
```

**willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:**

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    if(toInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape)
    {
        if(wasInPortrait){ screenHeight = bounds.width }
        else { screenHeight = bounds.height }
    }
    else
    {
        if(wasInPortrait){ screenHeight = bounds.height }
        else { screenHeight = bounds.width }
    }

    self.tableView!.reloadData()

}
```

**ViewDidLoad:**

```
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
var screenHeight: CGFloat!
var wasInPortrait = true

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
   super.viewDidLoad()

   screenHeight = bounds.height

   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape { wasInPortrait = false }

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.rateMe() }

}
```

Comment: You are not changing the header height based on the orientation, you are changing it based on section number

Comment: Yes I need specifically section 1 to change height on orientation change?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, makes more sense now